# Excuse an undeclared variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, nonetype

I'm new to beautifulsoup in python and I"m trying to extract certain information from a website. The deeplink, title and the price.

It is working fine, I also managed to remove the duplicates.

But the issue that I have is that I have an undeclared variable which I would like to change into an defined/declared variable. To be honest, I dont know how do it.

Following example:

```
already_printed = set()

while page <= max_pages:
    page += 1
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.jser.com/s/search.json?q=" + str(Region)
    jsondata = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
    format = (jsondata['activities'])
    g_data = format.strip("'<>()[]\"` ").replace('\'', '\"')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(g_data)
    #print(soup)


    hallo = soup.find_all("article", {"class": "activity-card activity-card-horizontal "})


    for item in hallo:
        headers = item.find_all("h3", {"class": "activity-card"})
        for header in headers:
            header_final = header.text.strip()
            if header_final not in already_printed:
                already_printed.add(header_final)
```

As far as I know, I have removed the duplicates from my header element but created an undeclared variable.

I tried to create a variable:

```
Test = already_printed.add(header_final)
```

but obviously it does not work. Can anyone help me out? How should I approach that problem? Any feedback is appreciated?

**EDIT**

I´m getting the following response:

```
None
None
None
None
None
```

My goal would be to store the output (header, price and deeplink) in a MySQL Databank. But without having a variable it does not work to transfer it into the databank. Hence, I´m asking how to define a variable from an undeclared variable

Comment: Do you get an error? If yes *what* error? Please copy & paste the whole error message in your question. Otherwise clarify which variable are you talking about and why you want to change that even if it raises no error.

Comment: BTW :`set` already removes duplicates. You don't have to manually check before adding.  Your whole inner `for` loop could be replaced by `already_printed.update(header.text.strip() for header in headers)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Or even a set comprehension if OP wants.

Comment: You don't declare `Region` here, if you're getting a `NameError` that could be why.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I have updated my task description. I hope, it makes sense:)